# Context meaning for paragraph

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I was reading this paragraph and it very hard for me to understand the words marked in bold. Please help me out.

As far as the economy is concerned, 2016 could be characterised as a year with two halves. It started with things looking up for India. **The global situation, on balance,** was benign. The foreign policy energy displayed by the Narendra Modi government was beginning to bear fruit and India was the bright spot in a world searching for growth. **To its credit,** the government was looking ahead and trying to reconfigure **India’s economic architecture through new institutional mechanisms**, such as the one to tackle monetary policy. However, over the second half things unravelled both at home and abroad.

I have following questions:

1. What is global situation and how is it balanced?
2. What is the credit, the writer is talking about ?
3. What is economic architecture?

I read the passage from link:
http://blogs.timesofindia.indiatimes.com/toi-editorials/a-volatile-year-2016-ends-with-the-economy-facing-headwinds-reform-is-the-only-antidote/

Comment: For the meaning of #1, see [this dictionary entry](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/on-balance).

Answer (score 2):

> 1. What is global situation and how is it balanced?

The author is referring to the global situation with regards to economics, as indicated in the previous sentence which talks about India's positive economic start to the year. They are not saying that the global situation was balanced, but using "on balance" to mean "overall" or "when all factors are taken into consideration". So saying "The global situation, on balance, was benign." in this specific instance means the same as "The global economic situation, when all factors are taken into account, was mild/favourable.".

> 2. What is the credit, the writer is talking about?

They are saying that credit is due to the government in question for looking ahead, essentially offering praise to that government for looking ahead, stating that it was a good thing to do.

> 3. What is economic architecture?

I presume you know what economics means - the science of production, distribution and consumption of goods and services or generally financial considerations. Architecture is usually used to refer to the design and construction of buildings (or computer hardware/software), but can be used generally to refer to the structure of anything.

So what the author is referring to here is potential changes to the organisational and procedural structures of India's economy - for example making changes to laws around how money laundering is detected, splitting up a national bank into smaller pieces, or changing how the internal revenue service within government works in India.

Answer (score 0):

1. The phrase "on balance" is parenthetical, and can be removed without changing the meaning of the sentence. It indicates that the viewpoint of the author is balanced [neutral] (in his opinion). The sentence could be re-written as:

> Taking a balanced point of view, the global situation was benign.

2. The phrase "To its credit" simply means "In its favour" (and refers to the government). So:

> In the government's favour, it was looking ahead...

3. The phrase "economic architecture" means "economic organisation", i.e. how the economy is designed to work.